# How to use TextRazor Python library to analyze text

Tags: python, semantics

I'm trying to use TextRazor Python library in order to make some semantic analysis on a piece of text.

my text is defined as follows:

```
def text():
    return r"""Bla Bla Bla"""
```

When I run the method "analyze" from the above library on the above tet, I get the following error:

```
post_data = [("text", text.encode("utf-8")),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Does anyone know how I should define my text so TextRazor Python library can read it? BTW, the same text work fine with OpenCalais Python library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`analyze` takes a unicode object as a parameter, from your snippet and the `AttributeError` it looks like you are passing in a function.  If you call `analyze` directly with your content it should work.

```
 client.analyze(u"bla bla bla")
```

I work on TextRazor, if this doesn't help feel free to send a larger section of your code to support@textrazor.com and we'll be able to dig in a bit deeper.

Answer (score 2):

The error doesn't have anything to do with textrazor. It is because you are calling `encode` on a function object rather than a string object.

```
def text():
    return r"""Bla Bla Bla"""

# INCORRECT: calling encode on the function object.
text.encode("utf-8")

# CORRECT: calling encode on the string returned by the function
text().encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score -1):

After investigating the issue with TextRazor, they cam up with a solution, and it had nothing to do with the text definition.
Apparently, when you analyze text, you should perform "set_do_cleanup_HTML(False)" first, so TextRazor engine will not try to clean up empty HTML string. Therefore, the code should look as follows:

client.set_do_cleanup_HTML(False)

response1 = client.analyze(text())

Best.

Comment: -1 because the error in your question has nothing to do with textrazor. See my answer for the explanation